# What index or other database to use to speed this aggregating query up

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have stored a time series in a MySQL table 
[int(11) int(11)]
The first column is epoch time in milliseconds, the second column is the value at that time.

There are 25920000 records.
When I want to plot the data, I don't want to plot every millisecond but only at a certain resolution, I use the following query:

### Average per day

```
 SELECT AVG(value) FROM measurements GROUP BY ts DIV (1000*60*60*24)
```

This takes already 1,5 minutes which is way longer than I want to achieve.

Is there a certain index I might be able to use to speed up this query?

Or is there maybe another DBMS that is better suited for this.

as requested in comments:

### Original CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (ts INT(11), value INT(11))
```

### Sample Values

```
15151,11
15152,15
15153,50
15154,100
....
```

Note that I'm currently experimenting with integer data, in the future it will be floating point data

Comment: Your existing create table statement and some sample data would be helpful (i.e. export some data, so readers can trivially test/reproduce your scenario by copying and pasting the sql in the question into a test db).

Comment: You can add indexed columns "second", "minute" and prefill it and later group by it.

Comment: Also there are more than 60 milliseconds in a second :)

Comment: is your "resolution" (60*60*60*24) a fixed one, or do you change them / is it variable?

Comment: division is a very slow mathematical operation. Doing it 25920000 will add up. Can't you just juse left shift or right shift?

Comment: @fancyPants  Ow. Big fail :D

Comment: @e4c5 the sort of operation is actually irrelevant here. Division itself takes nanoseconds. Problem is that this requires full scan.

Comment: @Andrey indeed the main probably is probably the fact that ALL data is used.

Comment: @Olli There will probably a fixed number of resolutions (seconds, minutes, hours, days)

Comment: @Andrey come to think of it you are right

Comment: are your sure your figures are correct 25920000 / (60*60*24*1000) = 0.3

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **PERSISTENT** Columns that will be generate the date on the fly and also has an index

```
CREATE TABLE `measurements ` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datum` date AS (DATE(ts)) PERSISTENT,
  `ts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `datum` (`datum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: is this a functionality that MySQL has, or is it a feature of MariaDB? I'm not quite sure as i couldn't find a quick answer to that.

Comment: Should I maybe use another database?

Comment: its also in MySQL. in MariaDB starts it with Version 5.2. I have change my Answer, there was an error in calculation

Answer (score 1):

to speed up things (and to make sure an index might be used successful) you could add different columns for your resolutions and precalculate those from the timestamp value. 
After that, add indexes to this (these) columns and it should be faster since you do not have to calculate all the values before grouping with it.

i know its not the best flexible way but probably a good tradeoff.

Edit: If you fill this table you can also precalculate those values right off, so no need to recalculate lots of data.

Comment: I believe this is the only way. Or use different database.

Comment: @andrey What database would you recommend?